# Holding `jj` leaves inserted `j` character in Neovim

Tags: macos, escaping, neovim, keymaps

I'm trying to map `jj` to `<Esc>` but it's not working as expected.

I've tried adding these to keymaps in my `init.lua`, but it's not behaving as expected:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('i', 'jj', '<Esc>', { noremap = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i', 'jj', '<Esc>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

The problem is that when I press and hold `j` it types two `j`'s and then escapes to normal more and removes one of the `j`'s, leaving one `j` inserted before it goes to normal mode.

In my old .vimrc (not neovim) I had this `imap jj <Esc>` and it worked as expected

I'm working off a fresh clone of kickstart.nvim: https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim/blob/master/init.lua (@ commit d0b47ce)

Answer (score -1):

It works fine for me. I think problem lies in your os settings or keyboard interval time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).